Downsampling an image in the right way
I was not shure where to ask this question, but SE Data Science seems to be the best place for it.
So I tried to build a CNN based super resolution model. Unfortunately I have only high-res images but for training I need both: A high-res image and its low-res counterpart. It seems to be very easy to obtain the low-res image in this case: Just downsample the original image on your PC (eg. by using tensorflow‘s image.rescale). But  there is a problem:
Downsampling can be done using bilinear, bicubic or even nearest-neighbors (so just deleteing every second pixel). I noticed that the outcome of the super-resolution strongly depends on the type of downsampling I use. Sometimes (when just deleting every other pixel for scaling down) the super-resolved image does not even surpass simple bicubic upscaling in quality! And most papers I read about super-resolution do not just delete every other pixel but use bilinear or bicubic downsampling to get the low-res image. Especially in these cases the super-resolution model can surpass the bicubic upscaling in quality (at least from my experiments).
Now my question is:
What is the (physically) most realistic technique  for downsampling? Lets say I have a camera wich can make 100x100 px images and one that can make 50x50 px images: Can I just delete every second pixel to go from 100x100 to 50x50 or is bicubic downscaling more physically realistic? Is there any literature about this?
Thank you a lot for answering!

After some time I noticed that there is some literature about „real world super resolution“. They usually try to train a model by using images downsampled with different methods and randomly switching between them. With that, the model is much more general and can create images from different downsampled inputs.
I, however, suppose that this is also impacting the model performance. On one hand, the model has to be more powerful to learn all the downsampling kernels. On the other hand, the model has du guess more when producing a high-resolution image.
So if you are interested in very accurate image super-resolution with very few „hallucinations“, you should infer the downsampling kernel from the physics and train the model just with that kernel.
